# OSG не работает с GDAL на Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt

Работаю на Windows 10 x64
IDE: QtCreator 4.8.0 Based on Qt 5.12.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
Содержание .pro файла в самом низу, если он нужен.

**Есть минимальный пример OSG (main.cpp)** :

```
#include <osgDB/ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>
#include <ogrsf_frmts.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   // OGRPoint p;
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> root = osgDB::readNodeFile("../resourses/cessna.osg");
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
    viewer.setSceneData(root.get());

    return viewer.run();
}
```

Компилируется, запускается и отображает самолет (модель cessna.osg). Но если я раскомментирую первую строчку, то код тоже компилируется и запускается, но окно 
с самолетом не появляется. Словно у меня пустой `main`. На линуксе этот же код  работает отличано. Почему так может происходить?

**.pro файл, если он влияет** :

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = hello
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
main.cpp


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target


#<--------------------- OSG Library
win32 {

    OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY = $$(OSG_BIN)
    OSG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY = $$(OSG_INCLUDE)

    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {

        TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,_d)

        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgd
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgViewerd
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgDBd
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -lOpenThreadsd
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgUtild
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgGAd
    } else {

        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losg
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgViewer
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgDB
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -lOpenThreads
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgUtil
        LIBS += -L$$OSG_LIB_DIRECTORY -losgGA

    }

    INCLUDEPATH += $$OSG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY
}

unix {

    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {

        TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,_d)

        LIBS += -losgd
        LIBS += -losgViewerd
        LIBS += -losgDBd
        LIBS += -lOpenThreadsd

    } else {

        LIBS +=  -losg
        LIBS +=  -losgViewer
        LIBS +=  -losgDB
        LIBS +=  -lOpenThreads

    }
}
#--------------------- OSG Library !>

HEADERS += $$OSG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY


#<--------------------- GDAL Library
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += D:/Interface/Work/Libs/gdal/include/
    LIBS += D:/Interface/Work/Libs/gdal/lib/libgdal-20.dll
}

unix {
    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lgdal
}
#--------------------- GDAL Library !>
```

Comment: Окно не появляется, ок, а что происходит? OGRPoint создается? Код с созданием окна выполняется или до него не доходит? И пример не воспроизводимый, так как отсутствуют инклюды.

Comment: Добавил в код нужные заголовочные. Попробовал поставить точку останова, но прога не остановилась на ней. Остановы ставил на создании OGRPoint и на создании root. Если закомментировать, то точка останова на root работает.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что к библиотеке GDAL прилагается libgdal-20.dll, путь к которому я не прописал. Решил тем, что скопировал .dll файл в каталог с бинарником и все заработало.